# Handling Haskell zlib decompression errors

Tags: haskell, gzip, haskell-zlib

I have a String `x` which may or may not be gzip-compressed. Using the [`zlib`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib) library, I want to try decompressing `x` -- if it succeeds, the function shall return the compressed String. If not (i.e. `x` is not gzip-compressed) I want to simply return `x`.

As `GZip.decompress` generates an `error` if applied to a non-gzip string, I could use `catch` or similar, but I'm specifically asking for a solution that uses the `zlib` error handling mechanism.

How can I write a function, say `decompressIfPossible :: ByteString -> ByteString` that has the previously described characteristics? I'd prefer a `Either String ByteString` to represent either the error or the decompression result.

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show research effort, as it was immediately answered in a Q&A-style manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function from `zlib` you need to use here is called [`decompressWithErrors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-0.5.4.1/docs/Codec-Compression-Zlib-Internal.html#v%3adecompressWithErrors). Its value is the recursive `DecompressStream` data structure that you can fold to a `ByteString` using [`v:fromDecompressStream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-0.5.4.1/docs/Codec-Compression-Zlib-Internal.html#v%3afromDecompressStream)

Here's a full example of how to write the function you asked for:

```haskell
import Data.Either
import Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

-- | Convert & unfold the custom DecompressStream
--   error format from zlib to a Either
decompressStreamToEither :: DecompressStream -> Either String LB.ByteString
decompressStreamToEither (StreamError _ errmsg) = Left errmsg
decompressStreamToEither stream@(StreamChunk _ _) = Right $ fromDecompressStream stream
decompressStreamToEither StreamEnd = Right $ ""

-- | Decompress with explicit error handling
safeDecompress :: LB.ByteString -> Either String LB.ByteString
safeDecompress bstr = decompressStreamToEither $ decompressWithErrors gzipOrZlibFormat defaultDecompressParams bstr

-- | Decompress gzip, if it fails, return uncompressed String
decompressIfPossible :: LB.ByteString -> LB.ByteString
decompressIfPossible bstr =
    let conv (Left a) = bstr
        conv (Right a) = a
    in (conv . safeDecompress) bstr
```

Note that this example uses [`gzipOrZlibFormat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zlib-0.5.4.1/docs/Codec-Compression-Zlib-Internal.html#v%3agzipOrZlibFormat) which automatically detects if the header is a zlib or a gzip header.