# http-conduit: Transfer data using gzip

Tags: haskell, gzip, content-encoding, http-conduit

I intend to fetch a large amount of data over HTTP/HTTPS using `http-conduit`. In order to do this efficiently, I want to use the `Accept-Encoding: deflate,gzip` header to allow the server (if supported) to transfer the data in a compressed way.

However, some of the servers I want to fetch from seem to incorrectly respond with the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header while not returning gzip data.

Therefore I need to handle these cases:

- Server does not support compression --> Return plain response body
- Server returns gzipped/deflated content --> Return decompressed response body
- Server says (in response headers it returns gzipped content, but gzip decoding fails --> Return plain response body

In the third case, it can (in this specific case) safely be assumed, that the plaintext, uncompressed data does not look like gzip data, so *Response headers say it is gzipped && un-gzip fails* is fully equivalent to *The data is not compressed*.

How can I do this using `http-conduit`?

*Note:* This question intentionally does not show research effort because it has been answered immediately in a Q&A-style way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this answer more concise, we will use code & concepts from some of my previous posts:

- `simpleHttpWithManager` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310691/2597135)
- Tolerant gzip/deflate decoding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21770637/2597135)

To avoid redundancy, I will first explain the basic steps and then provide a full example.

First, we shall handle sending the headers. Note that wile [`http-types`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types) contains `hContentEncoding`, `hAcceptEncoding` is not predefined. Besides that, this is a trivial task.

After sending the request, we need to check if there is a `Content-Encoding`. If there is none, we shall assume uncompressed plaintext, else we need to check if it is `gzip` or `deflate`. Which one it is exactly does not matter in this context as [`zlib`] supports automatic detection by header.

For this rather simple example we just assume that if the server returns a `Content-Encoding` value that is neither absent nor `gzip` nor `deflate`, the response is not compressed. As we did not allow (by `Accept-Encoding`) other compressions like `sdch`, the server would be violating the HTTP standard by acting that way.

If we detect a compressed encoding, we try to decompress and return it. If this fails or if the data is not compressed at all, we return the plain response body.

Here's the example:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Network.Connection
import Codec.Compression.Zlib.Internal
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Either
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB

myurl :: String
myurl = "http://stackoverflow.com"

hAcceptEncoding :: HeaderName
hAcceptEncoding = "Accept-Encoding"

-- | The Accept-Encoding HTTP header value for allowing gzip or deflated responses
gzipDeflateEncoding :: ByteString
gzipDeflateEncoding = "gzip,deflate"

-- HTTP header list that allows gzipped/deflated response
compressionEnabledHeaders :: RequestHeaders
compressionEnabledHeaders = [(hAcceptEncoding, gzipDeflateEncoding)]

-- | Give an encoding string and a HTTP response object,
--   Checks if the Content-Encoding header value of the response object
--   is equal to the given encoding. Returns false if no ContentEncoding
--   header exists in the given response, or if the value does not match
--   the encoding parameter.
hasResponseEncoding :: ByteString -> Response b -> Bool
hasResponseEncoding encoding response =
    let responseEncoding = lookup hContentEncoding headers
        headers = responseHeaders response
    in maybe False (== encoding) responseEncoding

-- | Convert the custom error format from zlib to a Either
decompressStreamToEither :: DecompressStream -> Either String LB.ByteString
decompressStreamToEither (StreamError _ errmsg) = Left errmsg
decompressStreamToEither stream@(StreamChunk _ _) = Right $ fromDecompressStream stream
decompressStreamToEither StreamEnd = Right $ ""

-- | Decompress with explicit error handling
safeDecompress :: LB.ByteString -> Either String LB.ByteString
safeDecompress bstr = decompressStreamToEither $ decompressWithErrors gzipOrZlibFormat defaultDecompressParams bstr

-- | Decompress gzip, if it fails, return uncompressed String
decompressIfPossible :: LB.ByteString -> LB.ByteString
decompressIfPossible bstr =
    let conv (Left a) = bstr
        conv (Right a) = a
    in (conv . safeDecompress) bstr

-- | Tolerantly decompress response body. As some HTTP servers set the header incorrectly,
--   just return the plain response text if the compression fails
decompressResponseBody :: Response LB.ByteString -> LB.ByteString
decompressResponseBody res
    | hasResponseEncoding "gzip" res = decompressIfPossible $ responseBody res
    | hasResponseEncoding "deflate" res = decompressIfPossible $ responseBody res
    | otherwise = responseBody res

-- | Download like with simpleHttp, but using an existing manager for the task
--   and automatically requesting & handling gzipped data
simpleHttpWithAutoGzip :: Manager -> String -> IO LB.ByteString
simpleHttpWithAutoGzip manager url = do req <- parseUrl url
                                        let req' = req {requestHeaders = compressionEnabledHeaders}
                                        fmap decompressResponseBody $ httpLbs req' manager

-- Example usage
main :: IO ()
main = do manager <- newManager conduitManagerSettings -- Create a simple manager
          content <- simpleHttpWithAutoGzip manager "http://stackoverflow.com"
          -- Print the uncompressed content
          print $ content
```